# What is the maximum number of queues that can be supported by MSMQ?

Tags: msmq

What is the maximum number of queues that can be supported by MSMQ?  Does the maximum vary by operating system?  Does the maximum vary if the queues are public or private?

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the amount of memory you have alloted. but what you can't have are message exceeding 4MB.

Resource Management in MSMQ Applications

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms811056.aspx

Answer (score 1):

1. Depends on memory.
2. Yes.
3. Yes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms811056.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms882845.aspx